# ¿Cómo puedo probar que exista un campo en un respuesta usando RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Estoy haciendo las pruebas para un `API en RoR`. Quiero validar la estructura de una respuesta hacia una petición de mi API. Quiero asegurarme que existe un campo en particular de esa respuesta y si no existe indicar que la prueba falla.

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

describe "POST #create" do

    context "when logged in with identifier" do

        before(:each) do
            @user_attributes = { identifier: user[:email], password: '12345678' } 
            post :create, { session: @user_attributes }
        end

        it"when is valid token" do
            #como valido que en la respuesta exista el token
        end
    end
end
```

El `response` de la petición es el siguiente:

```
{"user": 
  {
   "id":9005,
   "email":"kayden_schmidt@pfeffer.co.uk",
   "first_name":"Serenity",
   "middle_name":"Keagan",
   "last_name":"O'Kon",
   "birthday":"2014-07 -01T04:30:00.000Z"
  },
 "token":"....."
 }
```

Estoy usando `RSpec 3.3.0` y `Rails 4.2.3`

Comment: Si mi respuesta te sirve pero requiere de una pequeña modificación, es mejor que hagas un comentario explicando el problema y yo actualizo el contenido de la misma. Si no, es mejor que publiques una nueva respuesta con la solución que hayas encontrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces una llamada a post, obtienes o deberías obtener como respuesta un objeto `response`. Yo te recomiendo que lo parsees a JSON para manipularlo mejor.

```
it "when is valid id" do
  expect(JSON.parse(response.body).first.keys.include?("id")).to be(true)
end
```

En general la clave esta en parsear como JSON y hacer algo con el objeto `response.body`.

Comment: tu respuesta me funciono, pero debido al resultado de mi response tuve que adaptarla, pero la idea principal estuvo genial! gracias